# Create an http response writer on top of net.Conn

Tags: http, go

In the following code:

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)
assert(err)
c, err := l.Accept()
assert(err)
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(TLS_CERT, TLS_PKEY)
assert(err)
TLSconfig := &tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    ClientAuth:   tls.VerifyClientCertIfGiven,
    ServerName:   DOMAIN_NAME,
}
tlsConn := tls.Server(c, TLSconfig)
tlsConn.Handshake()
c = net.Conn(tlsConn)
```

I would like to create an http response writer, e.g.:

```
w := CreateResponseWriter(c)  //<-- how to do this?
w.Header().Set(...)
if !Authorized(c.RemoteAddr()) {
    http.Error(w, "Unauthorized", http.StatusUnauthorized)
    return
}
data, _ := os.Open("/path/to/content")
defer data.Close()
io.Copy(w, data)
```

The purpose is that I am writing an http proxy in Golang, I will need to check if the remote connection is authorized or not, if not, I will show the login page.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you get this info from parsed http request? Have you seen another proxy solutions like go-proxy?

Comment: Are you aware of [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy)? It does all the heavy lifting (writing a correct proxy is hard). You can set the Director function or the Transport field to do what you want I think.

Comment: I am not "reverse" proxying. I just saw a blog post on write a proxy with go, and decided to write my own as it looks pretty easy. And my proxy is working now.    Also I have tried httputil.ReversProxy in my other project, it works well too, but not for my case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http.ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) is an interface. So to create your own, just make any data type that satisfies the interface.

But it looks like what you're really trying to do is just bind your HTTP server to an existing connection. For that you can use the [Serve](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Serve) or [ServeTLS](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.ServeTLS) methods.